# Inverted parentheses in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is it about Javascript that lets me use inverted / backwards parentheses in function calls like this?  I'm running in a Node console on the CLI; specifically Node version 0.10.25.

```
function a(){ return 42 }
a() // -> 42
a)( // -> 42.  WTF?

function b(t){ return t }
b(4) // -> 4
b)4( // No function evaluation; presumably dangling parentheses
b)(4 // -> 4.  WTF?
```

Addendum: This doesn't appear to work in Chrome 33.0.1750.152, Safari 7.0.2, or Firefox 27.01.  Is this actually some kind of "feature" of some interpretation of ECMAScript, or a Node peculiarity?  If Node is using V8, shouldn't it match up with the Chrome results?

Comment: `Unexpected token )` in Chrome. `Expected ';'` in IE 11.

Comment: This definitely doesn't work on Google Chrome

Comment: Couldn't reproduce it on firefox aswell

Comment: Perhaps this is browser-specific behavior?  I'd think the language would clearly define any errors in this, but perhaps not?  (Or perhaps some browsers didn't implement it like that?)

Comment: it works on Node console and only in Node console. A bug?

Comment: Have you tried it in a JS file?  I'm guessing this has to do with the REPL, and not JavaScript.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this question?  If you're going to downvote this question you should explain why.  There is nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: ``I'm running in a Node console on the CLI.`` maybe this is a specific behavior of Node

Comment: It does work with node !

Comment: Maybe it's being interpreted as `(b)(4)`?

Comment: Presumably an artifact of the parser on the REPL?

Comment: Tested with a JS file and it did not work. Interactive did work. Seems like a Node bug to me.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I assume the browser is auto-correcting bad syntax to the correct ().

Comment: It doesn't work in the node-webkit either

Comment: I'm betting node's code is evaluated in a pair of `()`, so it becomes `(b)(4)`

Comment: node REPL uses `eval` for each line given.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is possible that the console wraps everything inside an eval statement: what is actually
evaluated is maybe eval(a)(). In that case Chrome returns 42 as well.

Comment: Or even just a set of parentheses: `a)(` => `(a)()`

Comment: Alright now who's going to look inside all the node.js source code to verify that?

Comment: +1 This is definitely the case. If you read here in the docs, you'll see that each line is evaluated using eval: http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html `eval - function that will be used to eval each given line. Defaults to an async wrapper for eval()`

Comment: Guessing this is the line right here: `evalCmd = '(' + evalCmd + ')\n';` https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/repl.js#L268

Comment: I'm surprised the eval doesn't consider the line as a string.  In that case, `eval("a)(")` results in the same trailing-parens non-evaluation.

Comment: Based on what @cookiemonster found, it's evaluating as `eval('(a)()')`

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte: The cause isn't so much that it's in an `eval` call, but more specifically that the code is wrapped in `"("` and `")"` before being `eval`'d.

Comment: @cookiemonster For sure. I was just commenting that it was, indeed, using `eval` Good find there in `repl.js` which totally clears up what's going on.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte: Sure, just that the answer isn't quite right the way it reads. I'm not even sure that it's actually `eval` that's used, otherwise the code would be able to access the internal local variables. Probably uses the `Function` constructor, or something else. Or maybe it sends it to a safe scope before evaluation. But that's beside the point. We can think of it as `eval` either way.

Comment: Likewise, defining function a () { return function () { return 2; } }  causes 'a)()(a' to return 2